# WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

Just wondering, in the android documentation, WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION is not stated as a Broadcast like the others. Can I write a broadcast receiver having an intent-filter in the manifest as SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION? My question is does `WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION` fire a broadcast intent that I can filter for?

Comment: Thanx guys, I have the answer

Comment: Then you should answer the question

Comment: what is the answer?